# "Plus" button in Django forms : user-added fields possible?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I've tried looking for some answer on Google and here on SO, but I'm really struggling finding anything even remotely connected to my problem.
I have toyed around with Formsets, Model choice field and such, with no results.

So here it is : I have a form from which a user can create NPCs (Non-player characters) with a name, a class, a level, and a skill.
The number of possible skills isn't fixed, so a NPC could have 3 skills as he could have 10, depending on the user's needs.
Is it possible to give the user the possibility to add "skill" fields (dropdown bars) to this form on the fly, for example with an "add skill" button ?

Is there a way to do this with Django/Python (including additional django modules), or would it be easier with, say, Javascript ?

Thanks a lot to anyone reading this, and for any helpful answer that could point me in the right direction !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use checkboxes for the skills, and that way the user could check all the skills they want?

If you're set on the add-a-field option though, you will probably want/need to use Javascript to add the new form field(s). However, handling the form after it is submitted will not change much, and will still take place in your same Django view.

Here is a brief code example that does what you want:

```js
function confirm(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display = "block";
  return false;
};

function addSkill() {

  var newSkillField = document.createElement("LI");
  selectNode = `
            <select form="npc_form" name="npc_skills">
            <option value="skill_one">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="skill_two">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="skill_three">Skill 3</option>
            <option value="skill_four">Skill 4</option>
        </select>
    `;
  newSkillField.innerHTML = selectNode;

  var skill_list = document.getElementById("skill-list");
  skill_list.insertBefore(newSkillField, document.getElementById("add-skill-li"));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


  <form action="/your-url/" method="post" id="npc_form">
    <br>
    <label for="npc_name">Name: </label>
    <input id="npc_name" type="text" name="npc_name" placeholder="NPC Name">

    <br>
    <label for="npc_class">Class: </label>
    <select form="npc_form" name="npc_class">
        <option value="class_one">Class 1</option>
        <option value="class_two">Class 2</option>
        <option value="class_three">Class 3</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <label for="npc_level">Level: </label>
    <input type="number" name="npc_level" min="1" max="100" value="1">

    <br>
    <label for="npc_skills">Skills: </label>
    <ul id="skill-list">
      <li>
        <select form="npc_form" name="npc_skills">
            <option value="skill_one">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="skill_two">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="skill_three">Skill 3</option>
            <option value="skill_four">Skill 4</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li id="add-skill-li">
        <input type="button" value="Add Skill" onclick="addSkill();" id="add-skill">
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- comment this out to actually submit -->
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirm();">

    <!-- uncomment this to actually submit -->
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
  </form>

  <p style="display: none; color: green;" id="confirmation">Submitted!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the same example, but using checkboxes instead:

```js
function confirm(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display = "block";
  return false;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


  <form action="/your-url/" method="post" id="npc_form">
    <br>
    <label for="npc_name">Name: </label>
    <input id="npc_name" type="text" name="npc_name" placeholder="NPC Name">

    <br>
    <label for="npc_class">Class: </label>
    <select form="npc_form" name="npc_class">
        <option value="class_one">Class 1</option>
        <option value="class_two">Class 2</option>
        <option value="class_three">Class 3</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <label for="npc_level">Level: </label>
    <input type="number" name="npc_level" min="1" max="100" value="1">

    <br>
    <label for="npc_skills">Skills: </label>
    <ul id="skill-list">
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="npc_skills" value="skill-one">Skill 1 </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="npc_skills" value="skill-two">Skill 2 </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="npc_skills" value="skill-three">Skill 3 </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="npc_skills" value="skill-four">Skill 4 </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- comment this out to actually submit -->
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirm();">

    <!-- uncomment this to actually submit -->
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
  </form>

  <p style="display: none; color: green;" id="confirmation">Submitted!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

In either case, use the following in your view to get the "npc_skills" as a list:

```
npc_skills = request.POST.getlist('npc_skills')
# if you selected/checked skills one and three: npc_skills = ['skill_one', skill_three']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked nicely, with a bit of tweaking to add some other elements and to adapt it to my project. Sticked with the dropdown options, as the number of skills is a wee bit too large to display comfortably with checkboxes. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Try this out.

in your html file

```
<form method="post" action="{{url}}">
    {% csrf_token %}        
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Skill</th>
                <th class="one"></th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in skill_formset.forms %}
                <tr class="check_items_row form_set_row">           
                    <td>
                        {{form.id}}
                        <span class="name">                             
                            {{ form.name }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="one">{% if form.instance.pk %}{{ form.DELETE }}{% endif %}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ skill_formset.management_form }}
     <div class="m-t-20">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect">Submit</button>
    </div> 
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.skill_formset table tr.form_set_row').formset({
    prefix: '{{ skill_formset.prefix }}',
    formCssClass: 'dynamic-formset1',
    });
});
```

The image shown is from my work that is created by jquery formset. I hope the same thing is you want.

Comment: Might be a useful answer if you give some context. What your class "one" looks like, etc.

Comment: Class one is using for assigning a width to the td and th.